# Import-Csv and Set-MailContact: How to set -ExtensionCustomAttribute1 to multi values

Tags: powershell

If I do this:

```
Set-MailContact -Identity $Alias -ExtensionCustomAttribute1 CLASS1,CLASS2
```

then set a filter for a Dynamic Distribution List like this:

```
-RecipientFilter { ExtensionCustomAttribute1 -eq "CLASS1" }
```

it correctly filters and sends emails to recipients with CLASS1 somewhere in their -ExtensionCustomAttribute1 property. So far, so good.

BUT, I want to set the -ExtensionCustomAttribute1 on the mail contacts using a CSV import and can't find the right syntax so that the csv field that contains CLASS1,CLASS2 gets assigned properly. After a csv import, sending an email to the dynamic list sends to those with ExtensionCustomAttribute1 of just `{CLASS1}`, but ignores those where it has more than one item in the array eg {CLASS2,CLASS1}

I am setting the csv delimiter like so to avoid the comma conflict:

```
$InputContacts = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter '|'
```

then the csv row (fragment) looks like:

```
|CLASS1,CLASS2|
```

and the statement looks like (where ECA1 is the column heading):

```
Set-MailContact -Identity $Alias -ExtensionCustomAttribute1 $Contact.ECA1
```

After `Set-MailContact`, when I dump the `Get-Recipient` for the mail contact it displays `{CLASS1,CLASS2}` so it looks right but the filtering is failing for some reason.

A clue is that when setting it directly via `-ExtensionCustomAttribute1 CLASS1,CLASS2` the property displays as `{CLASS2,CLASS1}` but when setting via the csv field it looks like `{CLASS1,CLASS2}` (ie the same order as in the csv field, not reversed) which seems to indicate it is saving it as a string rather than 2 array items. Could be coincidence though.

I am thinking I might need to parse that field and use a series of `@{Add=" "}` statements but that seems excessive!

Any ideas?
Thanks.

PS: I tried this `|"CLASS1","CLASS2"|` but it set the property to `{CLASS,"CLASS2"}` :=(

Comment: Sorry: typo in my PS. `{CLASS1,"CLASS2"}`

Comment: I get the reverse order in all tests including reading from a CSV first. It appears that the add is happening in LIFO order rather than FIFO order. It's weird but consistent on my end. Even if you do multiple `Set-MailContact` commands, I see the last added value at the front of the list.

Comment: When you are reading from the CSV, the `|` is your delimiter. That means anything between `|` characters is a string. So even though a `Get-MailContact` output appears to look the same, if you run `(Get-MailContact).ExtensionCustomAttribute1`, you will see the output is a single string rather than an array. The only way your recipient filter works is if the `ExtensionCustomAttribute1` value is a collection rather than a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are reading from the CSV, the `|` is your delimiter. That means anything between `|` characters is a string. So even though a `Get-MailContact` output appears to look the same (`{class1,class2}`). This is because the value of that attribute is a collection object type. If you run (Get-MailContact).ExtensionCustomAttribute1, you will see the output is a single string item (a collection of a single string) rather than an array of multiple strings. The only way your recipient filter works is if the `ExtensionCustomAttribute1` value is a collection of multiple strings.

In your case, you need to turn the `$Contact.ECA1` value into a comma-delimited value. You can use `Split()` method from the String class.

```
Set-MailContact -Identity $Alias -ExtensionCustomAttribute1 $Contact.ECA1.Split(',')
```

If the order matters to you, then you will need to add additional logic to handle order. One option is to cast the `$Contact.ECA1.Split(',')` as an `arraylist` and execute the `Reverse()` method.

```
$ECA1 = [Collections.Arraylist]$Contact.ECA1.Split(',')
$ECA1.Reverse()
Set-MailContact -Identity $Alias -ExtensionCustomAttribute1 $ECA1
```

When testing your scenarios, I get the reverse order in all tests including reading from a CSV first. It appears that the add is happening in LIFO order rather than FIFO order. It's weird but consistent on my end. Even if you do multiple Set-MailContact commands, I see the last added value at the front of the list.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed and helpful response. That did indeed solve the problem. I am very very new to PowerShell and your response was very educative.